# Getting table data with execute immediate in a loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to extract data from tables. The names of multiple tables can be given as comma separated values (like a,b,c) and based on that I need to extract the data into a file. Here is the code, which is run through SQL*Plus:

```
declare 
  p_schema_name varchar2(1000) := '&1';
  p_table_names varchar2(4000) := '&2';
  p_statement varchar2(4000);
begin
  p_statement := 'select * from :x'||'.'||':y';
  for foo in (    
    select 
      regexp_substr (replace(p_table_names, ' ', ''), '[^,]+', 1, level) as txt
    from dual
    connect by 
      regexp_substr (replace(p_table_names, ' ', ''), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
  loop
      execute immediate p_statement using p_schema_name, foo.txt;
  end loop;
end;
```

When I execute this script then I get the following error:

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06512: at line 14
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only bind variables, not object names. The bind substitution is done when your query is executed, not when it is parsed. The object names have to be known at parse time.

You have to concatenate the schema and table name into the query:

```
...
begin
  p_statement := 'select * from ';
  ...
      execute immediate p_statement || p_schema_name ||'.'|| foo.txt;
  end loop;
end;
```

Of course that now has the potential for [SQL injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01109), so you need to sanitise the inputs. You can check if they are valid names, or check the extracted tables exist in the specified schema before trying to execute the query. You might find [the DBMS_ASSERT package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm) useful.

Although your query won't actually be executed at the moment; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#CJABDAAE):

> If *dynamic_sql_statement* is a SELECT statement, and you omit both *into_clause* and *bulk_collect_into_clause*, then *execute_immediate_statement* never executes.

You need to select your data into something, which is going to be tricky if the tables that can be passed in have different structures. If you plan to write the queried data into a file and don't know the structure then you need to use [the DBMS_SQL package](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01108) rather then `execute immediate`.

Answer (score 1):

Table names and Column names cannot be passed as Bind variables to an Execute immediate statement!

Instead use them as variables and concatenate them.

But then the other error would be that you are missing an INTO clause for the Execute immediate statement processing a SELECT statement as said by the other contributor.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 1):

As per your question how you are  going to handle the output of SELECT * query from PLSQL. I guess you either need to have a ref cursor to anyway use this. Also as per your code if you loop through multiple tables the output will be always overwritten by the next one so you will get the last query output only.
So for this spool the output in a file and iterate to next table.

Hope this info helps.